# REST API Delete operation passing URL as a parameter

Tags: rest

I have a rest subscriber resource for which i would need to delete a subscriber if it matches the criteria of topic-name,country,lob and url.

http://localhost:8080/subscriber/topics/{topic-name}/{country}/{lob}/{url}

how should i send the request for the delete resource with URL escaping the special characters??

Sample below:

```
http://localhost:8080/subscriber/topics/FNOL/UK/mariane/https://endpoint.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{url}` path segment needs to be encoded.

`http://localhost:8080/subscriber/topics/FNOL/UK/mariane/https%3A%2F%2Fendpoint.com`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding